# how to install Scraping plugin "libweb-scraper-perl_0.36.orig.tar.gz "?

Tags: plugins

I have downloaded "libweb-scraper-perl_0.36.orig.tar.gz " from the link given below :

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/perl/libweb-scraper-perl

and it is in desktop folder, help me to install it in 32 bit ubuntu 14.04.2

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to install from source code. Easily you can just run the command to install:

```
sudo apt-get install libweb-scraper-perl
```

But you have to enable "Universe" repository if you don't have it yet.

To do that  open software center. Click on 'edit' and then 'software sources' to open the software sources window. Once that is open, check the box that says, "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands:

```
cd
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libw/libweb-scraper-perl/libweb-scraper-perl_0.36.orig.tar.gz
tar xf libweb-scraper-perl_0.36.orig.tar.gz
cd Web-Scraper-0.36
cpan Web::Scraper
perl Makefile.PL
make test
make install
```

<sub>Soure: Web-Scraper-0.36/README</sub>

Comment: i have installed it, and  showing in ubuntu software center also, but i cannot see the application for launching, from where i t will be stored for running?

Comment: This is a library. A library was not started. A library can be used by other programs.

Comment: Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Answer (score -1):

Go to the directory where you have downloaded `libweb-scraper-perl_0.36.orig.tar.gz` and run the following commands:

```
tar -zxvf libweb-scraper-perl_0.36.orig.tar.gz
```

This will extract the contents to a directory. Go to the directory by:

```
cd name-of-directory
```

and execute:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

If the package is available from Ubuntu (I am sure it is) you can easily install this using the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install libweb-scraper-perl
```

Comment: I tried but, it saying NO directory found in terminal

Comment: you should replace `name-of-directory` with the actual name of directory which will be I guess something like 'libweb-scraper-perl'. Also since you are using 14.04 I think you should get the 0.37-1 version. You can get the .deb file from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libweb-scraper-perl) and install it with `sudo dpkg -i libweb-scraper-perl_0.37-1_all.deb`

Comment: libweb-scraper-perl_0.36.orig.tar.gz   is the file name before extraction, after extraction it is   Web-Scraper-0.36  both files are in my desktop.

Comment: please dont make me to jump from one to another, i want a solution to install any webscraping software in linux for running..

Comment: Just because I suggested doesn't mean you have to 'jump' to it. The end result of posting a question is getting one or two 'probable' solution(s).

Comment: any solution to install any webscraping software to install via terminal? then please gave me the source code to apply in terminal

Comment: @Adityan check my answer below

Comment: it cannot be success may be i am new to ubuntu,... if i get source code to apply terminal and direct install it is good.

Comment: i have installed libweb-scraper-perl_0.36.orig.tar.gz in linux,  from where i found this programme for running?

Comment: There is no `./configure`